Edit SDO_GEOMETRY in ArcGIS Pro
I am new to Esri products.
I am trying to edit data (SDO_GEOMETRY) in Oracle DB in ArcGIS Pro but without success.

Install ArcGIS Pro 3.3 Standard + connect to Oracle DB (.sde file) - db user with sufficient privileges
Install ArcGIS Server 11.2 Standard (stand-alone) + Add new ArcGIS Server in my ArcGIS Pro (connection type = Publisher Connection)
Register a database to my ArcGIS Server (same as publisher database connection)
For Oracle table I publish map service with feature capabilities (edit geometry + attributes checkboxes checked)
Add features service to my ArcGIS Pro project and edit status is showing - This layer's workspace is read only. Workspace name: Feature Service Data MY_LAYER_NAME

I also tried to prepare Oracle spatial table like in this instruction but the edit status of the layer was the same:
https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/set-up-an-oracle-dbms-spatial-table-for-editing-via-a-f-000012057
Is it possible edit SDO_GEOMETRY in Esri products without enabling enterprise geodatabase and without using ST_GEOMETRY?

Editing a feature class with ArcGIS generally requires an enterprise geodatabase, but it does not have to be sde.ST_GEOMETRY. The document you cited indicates a procedure where it is apparently not required. You should probably [Edit] this to focus on that procedure.

Can you edit the geometry when connected to the database directly (.sde file) instead of when connected to the ArcGIS Server's feature service?  Going through ArcGIS Server requires a whole additional layer of permissions (and complications).

Edit sdo_geometry is not possible directly from ArcGIS Pro (sde file). You have to publish spatial table as feature service to ArcGIS Server. I checked edit permissions for feature service (map service with feature access + edit attributes and geometry) in ArcGIS Server manager´and it is right.

If I am following correctly, there is an Oracle DB & DB user that can edit, this DB is a data source in ArcGIS server, a feature service was created using the Oracle DB, and then in ArcPro, you added the feature as a layer. You want to be able to edit the features on your desktop via the feature service. One possible spot I see where there could be an issue, is the ArcGIS server connection made in ArcPro. Make sure that the ArcGIS server account that you are setting up the connection to the feature service via the server connection has the proper role to edit features.
